# Privacy with third-party accounts with Gmail app

Tags: gmail

When I add a third-party account (POP/IMAP) to the Gmail app, do emails for that account go through Google servers or directly to my phone? Is there a way to know whether the incoming or outgoing connections are secure (use SSL/TLS)?

Answer (score 0):

- On your device, Install [Packet Capture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture&hl=en) and you must install it's Certificate to decrypt SSL packets.
- Start Capture with Packet Capture.
- Launch your Gmail App and try to send a test email with your non-google account.
- Return to Packet capture and verify the sent packet.

Comment: Did anyone ever do this test?